# Problemas para guardar un DataFrame pandas enorme en csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Tengo un DataFrame de pandas tal que así:

```
col1     col2    col3

1           3       [-1.8888323233e-10, -1.998872201333-12...
3           1       [-3.88873222e-11, -2.9998882201...
2           0       [1.7877623108e-11, 9.0998230493...
1           3       [-6.8309211884e-10, -6.86332098341...
2           1       [3.31093872203-10, 3.1203973112..

270 rows × 2 columns
```

Donde la col 3 es una lista con longitud 1440000, cuando guardo el DataFrame en csv:

df.to_csv('C:/Users/......../groups.csv', index=False)

Me guarda todas las listas como string, es una única lista por línea de la col3 y lo abro así:

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/......../groups.csv')

La lista la podría guardar como sea (numpy array, float) pero que no sea string, he intentado cambiar el tipo con un bucle al abrir el csv, pero me da error.

También he visto al abrir el csv que no me ha guardado todos los elementos de las listas solo 102 en unos casos y en otros 96, **supongo que tiene que ver con la manera de guardar un DataFrame tan grande y con que son números flotantes**

OS Windows 10
Visual Studio Code

Alguna idea de cómo puedo guardarlo adecuadamente?
Se agradece de antemano!

Xavier

Answer (score 0):

El problema al que te enfrentas, se debe a conceptos errados sobre como funciona un csv. Así que aclararé algunas cosas:

- csv significa "comma-separated values" o "valores separados por comas". Y, justamente, si miras una fila de un csv, se ve así `a,"b,c",d`
- En ninguna parte del csv se guarda el tipo de valor, pero dicho puede tener cualquier letra, número o simbolo. Por lo que se asume el tipo string y le toca al programador determinar el tipo de una columna a la hora de abrir el csv. Supongo que esto es lo que hace pandas automaticamente.

Como notarás, el formato csv no acepta "arrays, arreglos o listas", por lo que te tocará obtener primero el valor como string y parsearlo aparte o convertir la lista en columnas del csv (esto conviene si son de tamaño fijo).

Lo primero lo podés hacer de varias formas dependiendo tus preferencias. La opción más limpia y más compatible con otros valores que se me ocurre es crear un csv dentro del csv. Esto quedaría así en cuanto a código:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import io

# parser para el csv interno
def get_floats(value):
    # Parseamos la primera fila del csv
    floats = next(csv.reader([value]))
    # Convertimos el contenido en flotantes
    return list(map(float, floats))

# unparser para el csv interno
def floats_to_csv(value):
    # Creamos un "archivo en memoria"
    stream = io.StringIO()

    #Escribimos la lista como csv
    csv.writer(stream).writerow(value)

    #obtenemos el contenido del "archivo"
    return stream.getvalue()

#Un "archivo en memoria" que contendrá el csv
csvfile = io.StringIO()

df = pd.DataFrame([["a", "b", [1.5, 1.6, 1.7]]], columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"])
df["col3"] = df["col3"].apply(floats_to_csv)
df.to_csv(csvfile)

# movemos el cursor al principio del archivo.
# esto es requerido para que read_csv lea desde el principio
csvfile.seek(0)

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, converters={"col3":get_floats})

# prints para ver el funcionamiento
floats = df.at[0, "col3"]
print(type(floats), floats)
print(type(floats[0]), floats[0])
```

Y así si vieras el csv:

```
col1,col2,col3
a,b,"1.5,1.6,1.7"
```

Aunque no haré un código para cada alternativa que se me ocurre para evitar extender mucho la respuesta, también podrías usar para guardar la lista:

- json: ahorra algo de trabajo, pero da una sintaxis un poco mas fea.
- simplemente, usar un formato csv simple (no compatible con comillas), los métodos de cadena split y join te serían de utilidad para esto.

Y probablemente haya otras alternativas. Podés elegir cualquiera de ellas. Pero como dije antes, no existen las listas en csv.

Comment: Gracias Dante!, entonces una solución un poco más sencilla, para mi, podría ser guardar la lista como strings 'sueltos' en cada fila y después convertirlos en arrays?

Comment: De nada! Y mi idea principal era, almacenar un csv en cada valor de la columna 3.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a la [respuesta](/a/611975) de [Dante](/users/158880), he tenido la idea de guardarlo en json, que controlo un poco más que csv. Por si ha alguien le sirve, lo he hecho así:
Para guardarlo...

```
with open('C:/Users/................/signal_groups.json', 'w') as json_file: 
      json.dump(dict_pos_groups, json_file, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
```

Para recuperarlo sin problemas...

```
with open("C:/Users/................/signal_groups.json") as archivo_json:
data = json.load(archivo_json)

df = pd.json_normalize(data)
```

He comprobado los parámetros de los datos de las filas y están bien cargados.

Comment: De nada nuevamente :) Hay casos donde conviene más usar tablas (como los csv) y otras donde los datos deben guardarse en estructuras más complejas (como json). Todo depende del escenario, y para tu caso veo usar json puro como buena idea.